# Twitter Bootstrap MVC: Filtering the Menu

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap, and the twitter.bootstrap.mvc project.  I have also pulled the Twitter Bootstrap for ASP.Net MVC 4 Sample.

The wiki page and the docs talk about filtering the menu based on rights, and I do see an example of how to write the filter and how to apply it:

https://github.com/erichexter/twitter.bootstrap.mvc/blob/master/src/Bootstrap/NavigationRouteFilterExamples/AdministrationRouteFilter.cs

https://github.com/erichexter/twitter.bootstrap.mvc/blob/master/src/Bootstrap/App_Start/ExampleLayoutsRouteConfig.cs

However, the following code doesn't work for me, as I don't have an overload that takes the 4th argument of NavigationRouteOptions:

```
routes.MapNavigationRoute<HomeController>("Administration Menu", 
                                          c => c.Admin(), "",
                                          new NavigationRouteOptions 
                                          { HasBreakAfter = true, FilterToken = "admin"});
```

When I browse the latest version of twitter.bootstrap.mvc on github, I don't even see the NavigationRouteConfigurationExtensions class.

I'm not sure what I'm missing.  Is there an updated version of the extension method clas in a different github project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the preview of Eric Hexter's nuget server here:

http://www.myget.org/F/erichexter/

It has the preview version with the code I seem to be missing.  I'm not clear on where the github repo for this code is.

The version of the package I was able to get doesn't allow filtering of child routes, but adding the code to make that work was relatively trivial.  You also can't link to the same path twice in the collection due to the way it names the routes, but (again) this was an easy fix.